# AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook Failed to authenticate user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When I started job with IAM Role **AWSGlueServiceNotebookRoleDefault** I have this error:

**Failed to authenticate user due to missing information in request.**

No information in docs about this error.

I do everything from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-notebook-policy.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role-notebook.html), I have two buckets crawler-public-service & aws-glue-service.

**GlueServiceNotebookPolicyDefault**:

```
{  
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[  
       {  
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[  
             "glue:CreateDatabase",
             "glue:CreatePartition",
             "glue:CreateTable",
             "glue:DeleteDatabase",
             "glue:DeletePartition",
             "glue:DeleteTable",
             "glue:GetDatabase",
             "glue:GetDatabases",
             "glue:GetPartition",
             "glue:GetPartitions",
             "glue:GetTable",
             "glue:GetTableVersions",
             "glue:GetTables",
             "glue:UpdateDatabase",
             "glue:UpdatePartition",
             "glue:UpdateTable",
             "glue:GetJobBookmark",
             "glue:ResetJobBookmark",
             "glue:CreateConnection",
             "glue:CreateJob",
             "glue:DeleteConnection",
             "glue:DeleteJob",
             "glue:GetConnection",
             "glue:GetConnections",
             "glue:GetDevEndpoint",
             "glue:GetDevEndpoints",
             "glue:GetJob",
             "glue:GetJobs",
             "glue:UpdateJob",
             "glue:BatchDeleteConnection",
             "glue:UpdateConnection",
             "glue:GetUserDefinedFunction",
             "glue:UpdateUserDefinedFunction",
             "glue:GetUserDefinedFunctions",
             "glue:DeleteUserDefinedFunction",
             "glue:CreateUserDefinedFunction",
             "glue:BatchGetPartition",
             "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
             "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
             "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
             "glue:UpdateDevEndpoint",
             "s3:GetBucketLocation",
             "s3:ListBucket",
             "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
             "s3:GetBucketAcl"
          ],
          "Resource":[  
             "*"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[  
             "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Resource":[  
             "arn:aws:s3:::crawler-public*",
             "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue*"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[  
             "s3:PutObject",
             "s3:DeleteObject"          
          ],
          "Resource":[  
             "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue*"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[  
             "ec2:CreateTags",
             "ec2:DeleteTags"
          ],
          "Condition":{  
             "ForAllValues:StringEquals":{  
                "aws:TagKeys":[  
                   "aws-glue-service-resource"
                ]
             }
          },
          "Resource":[  
             "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
             "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
             "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
          ]
       },
       {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "kms:Decrypt"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:kms:*:id:key/key-id"
         ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

**AWSGlueServiceNotebookRoleDefault**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I try to create new role with AWSGlueServiceRole + AmazonS3FullAccess, but still have the same error

Answer (score 9):

I was experiencing the same problem using chrome.
Solved it by going to
Chrome -> Settings -> Safety -> Cookies ->
Under user defined settings add a website that is always allowed cookies named
"[*.]aws.amazon.com"

I believe your roles are fine.

Comment: In Safari 15, there is no option to allow third party cookies for individual websites, so you are stuck with disabling "Prevent cross-site tracking" across the board from Preferences -> Privacy.

Comment: In Firefox 103, once you try to open the notebook and see the error, click on the shield icon on the left of the address bar, and disable "Enhanced Tracking Protection".

Answer (score 3):

This strange behavior reproduces in Safari. In Chrome all works perfect.

Comment: For me Firefox worked (v 101.0), but not Edge (v 102.0)

Answer (score 3):

This is Safari blocking third party cookies by default. The notebook domain and the AWS console domain are different and Safari will block cross-site cookies due to privacy (tracking) concerns.

You can allowlist the notebook domain or disable third party cookie blocking in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

On safari, you can go to Preferences > Privacy > Prevent Cross Site Tracking (disable the box of this). Then you should be able to use it as expected. This unblocks me from using Glue notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue 15.11.2022. I tried all the above and tried on several browsers/OS. We were able to repeat the issue on all of them, so we sent a support ticket to AWS and they replied that it was a data centre wide issue that was being resolved.
As of this morning it is resolved.